# Using the URLconf defined in learning_log.url,error 404

Tags: django

The python project about Django error
Using the URLconf defined in learning_log.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

A special answer for this question.

Comment: can you show me the complete error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.